# Looking for a manga about a guy who gets different girlfriends as a result of time travel

Tags: boku-to-kanojo-no-koi-log

The manga is about this guy who, even though he is a lolicon, gets a girlfriend after school one day while doing the cleaning chores. After that his little sister dies, and time is reversed without him knowing or remembering.

He now gets another, different, girlfriend. This chain of events keeps happening until he meets a girl that he created?

I don't remember the name, but I think it was a full manga, not a one-shot.

Comment: Sounds kind of like http://myanimelist.net/manga/58299/Girls_Go_Around but I haven't read the manga

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not 100% certain but it sounds a lot like [**Boku to Kanojo no Koi Log**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=70056). I've read this one completely (a little short, but still not bad).

The color spread from the first chapter for ease of identification.

[image: Chapter 1 color spread]

Chapter 9 and chapter 13 are where the story restarts with different girl. The protagonist followed his little sister the second time around and failed to save her from disappearing in chapter 12.